# Is there a way to make label prop in react native paper text input occupy more than one line?

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I'm using the [TextInput](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/TextInput/) component from the React Native Paper library. If the label is too long it shows an ellipsis at the end instead of wrapping the text to the next line.

I tried adding a custom component to the label prop with numberOfLines={2}. But it isn't working.

Here is the TextInput component

```
<TextInput
    label={
    <Text numberOfLines={2}>{Strings.banks_count_associated_with_ucv_lending}</Text>
    }
    value={formData$.peek()[PROFILE_FORM_FIELDS.ASSOCIATED_BANKS_COUNT] as string}
    onChangeText={(text) => updateFormData({key: PROFILE_FORM_FIELDS.ASSOCIATED_BANKS_COUNT, value: text})}
    required={true}
    outlineColor={colors.opacity_1}
    style={{height: 100, textAlignVertical: 'top'}}
    keyboardType="numeric"
/>
```

Comment: [numberOfLines](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/TextInput/#numberoflines--android-only) will work only in the android